# Why chrome is running processes in the background that make my PC unresponsive?

Tags: google-chrome, performance, microsoft-edge

Hey guys I have been running into a little problem with Chrome on my PC, its running read and write processes on the hard drive that significantly slow down itself and slows down the system drastically. The tabs become unresponsive and the system also becomes unresponsive after a certain period of usage. At first I thought it was the Hard Drive that was causing the bottleneck but other programs like Rider were running fine and were responsive though were effected upon by this chrome hard drive issue.

Today I decided to use Edge with as many tabs as I would on chrome and Edge does not lag for a single microsecond and the system is also fine. So this observation led me to conclude that it was Chrome that was causing the issue, maybe it was not releasing a hard drive write lock or something but something technical was happening and it was being caused by that program, I have also learnt that Edge has the edge in memory management but they use the same engine `Chromium`. If I ran as many tabs as I did below on Chrome, my system would struggle but using a different browser kind of solved the problem temporarily but I need to make Chrome stop behaving this way, Thank You for your help.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: Are you running the same version?  Edge and Chrome are both based on Chromium, I believe the current version is 101, but the simple solution is to just check to see if you are using the current version through the `about Chrome` functionality. You can [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound, I installed Chrome last year. Am not sure if it needs an update to fix the lag issue?

Comment: Edge is faster and does not throw ANR and does not make the system lag as a result

Comment: The experience gets worse that it even lags scrolling, imagine scrolling on a page becoming unresponsive due to a storage issue

Comment: @TechGeek - So update Chome and then [edit] your question to indicate if the problem still happens.  Your Edge installation is obviously current.  The performance differences between Chrome and Edge are trivial, on a modern system, you have not provided enough information to identify the real performance problem.

Comment: Which one is better between chrome and edge in terms of speed?

Comment: @TechGeek - They are identical.  I am not going to provide a specific recommendation since, software recoemdnations, are out of scope here at Super User.

Comment: okay what can I do apart from upgrade to tell chrome not to drag itself and the system down with it?